Was this Sanskrit text used for absolute beginners to use grammar if not what level
I found the Paribhāṣāpradīpārcis and the summary states, "Manuscript is an elementary grammatical treatise and commentary."
My question is is this Sanskrit text based on the first few pages intended historically for young beginner students and can you assign it a level like here for English ie 1st and 2nd grade? Using Sansript & SanskritCR here is a likely erroneous, but easier to read version.
Devanagri
*परिमा· श्रीगोशायनमः मन्दहृदयानंद निदानशिवयश्चिरम- नमस्कुरुत हेरम्बनिष्प्रत्यूहकलातये ९ वच्चक्रीपुस्त ककरां पुण्डरीका सनस्थिताम् - शारदांनीर कुंदेन्दुधवला भावतराम हवापाशि निसूत्राणी मित वृत्पर्थ संग्र हम-परिभाषाप्रदीपार्चिस्तत्रोपयनिरुतावत्परिभाषा नाम लिवत्वे सति संदिग्धार्थ नियामक त्वम् दीधीवेवीटा मिसादेर्नधा तुला १५ सादनिषेधः किमिक्परिभाषामा उत्तगुणा वृद्येोरिति संदिग्धार्थस्मनि यामकत्वात्परिभाषात्वस्यादतः स संतम् संज्ञा सूत्रागविधिप्रदेशीय संज्ञाबोधकपदरूप लिवत्वत्प नियामकत्वेनातिव्याप्तिः संदिग्घेति तथासतिक्वचिदेरेघोः क्रिरित्या दे। विशेषरूपे राग लोकप्रसिद्धार्थप्रसा कत्वात्क्वचित्पुनः सि चिनद्दिरि सादा व संदिग्धा येक वाद दोषः - परिभाषा रंगी तु सूत्रपात्राप्रदीपार्चिनां षष्ठी राम० अभियोग सादीनां विधिप्रदेशगत षष्टी पदादिश्रवणं रूप लिंग वत्वेन व्याख्यान इ सादीनां च ज्ञापकन्पा सिद्धानीसदिग्धपदादिश्रवरूप लिंग निसंदिग्धा थे नियामकला थोक व्यवहार सात वणोश्र
नास्ति पयलक्ष रामिक देश विकृतमनन्पद दिसादीनां निषेधातिदेशादिरूपाएंगे प्राचीन तथा व्यवहारः• माराध्यसाधादतएवनिपातए काजितिसूत्रेपन विधिस्तदेतस्याद्यंत वदेकस्मिन्नित्यनयोः संज्ञातिदेशस् त्रयः परिभाषा व्यवहार भाष्य या सांच कार्यनिवीहकत्वेपया व टमेन शास्त्र हरपते. प्रत्राद्यमा यथो देश संज्ञा परिभाष· उदय ते उच्चार्यते यस्मिन्म देना उच्चार कालः- अधिक रेगे घञ उदेना मनतिक म्पति यथेो देवराम यस्मिन्काले पूर्वत्र पत्र वा संज्ञायरिभाषं मुद्दिश्यते तत्रैव वा वनार्थ बोधेन ग्टहीताभ्यां संज्ञापद शक्तिपरिभाषार्थाभ्यां सर्वत्र शास्त्र व्यवहारः नन्विदमनुपपन्नम् - यावताका येथे वासंज्ञा परिभाषस्पका दशवृत्तित्वं न्याय्य मात्रा के यर-यदानुदिश्य प्रयोजन विशेष प्रयोजनमात्रमभिसंधाय भविष्यति किं चिट्नेन प्रयोजनमिति से ज्ञापरिभाषं प्रगीयते तदा संभव सेवा यं पे सो यथाश्रुतश्राहि पति पत्र प्रेस इति· महावाक्यार्थ पर्यालोचनप्रे वृत्त प्रतिपत्र पेस्तु द्दितीयः पपइसाह - कार्यकाल संज्ञा परिभाषम· कार्यर
परिभा· काल्पतेखसमीपं प्राप्यत इति कार्यकालम् कार्ये एस्व वृत्तिलिंग वत्संज्ञा परिभाषस्वोच्चार दिनों संनिधाप्यते इति यात. एवं चैतस्मिन दर्शन संज्ञा परिभाषा णाम संत पारार्थ्यान्न खाते से कार्य गमहेतुत्वं केवल माना मेरो लाघवापानेकप्रधानांग भावप्रतिपत्तये ष्टथगुपदेशः कृतः ततश्चहलनंतराः संयोगो ऽदर्शनं लोपः सुडिं. तं पदं षष्ठी स्थाने योगाला स्पस्पे त्पादिभिर्न किंचित्कार्य क्रियते नापि संयोगोत स्म लोप इसनेन किं तर्हिसह त्यातः संयोगातंय सदन] दंयस्प लोप इति महावाक्यार्थः संपद्यते इत्येकवाक्यता पोवपर्याभावात्पूर्वग्रहो नाग्रह एगज्ञा परिभाषा र पूर्वत्रा सिद्धमित्य सिद्धत्वं न प्रवर्तत इति स्षष्टं पूर्व नासिद्धमिति सूत्रे भाष्ये यत्र तु यथेोदेो वालियाघां प्रधान स्प संस्कार इष्यते यथा उ-मोहस्वादिलाद। सप्तमीपं चम्पुम ये निर्देवो परखा त्वच देवदयेनसुन तिचे धुने तिवद मुनेति वक्तव्ये सुक्ते योग विभागेन पूर्व वा सिड मित्पसिखा दयादिभिर्व स्त्रिया होने पादिकानी दिर्वचनादीनां केषांचि होना दुदुप
राम०
धस्पेति सूत्रे प्रत्ययस्येत्युक्ते व प्रधानोपस्कार का कचित्रिपाद्युपकारकत्वमंत्री करणी मं परादुमय निर्देशे पंचमी निर्देशोवली या निमितस्मिन्निति सूत्रं भाष्ंं व्याख्यात कार्यकालयतुमयेोरेकदेशस्य वि नपरत्वादित्युक्ते र संगतिः स्यात् वस्तुतस्तु उ. मइत्यनवकाशन पंचमी निर्देशेन मयउत्तरसूत्रे चरितार्थ सप्तमी निर्देश स्पतुल्पवलत्वाभावाद्दिप्रतिषेधातिरेकदेशिनः शितु पित्रनश्चेति पूर्वसूत्रचरितार्थामानइ तिपंचम्पावकाशेनशी तिसप्तमी निर्देशन वाधनेग संतरा भावाच अतएवा कडारीयभा दिसेज्ञानां त्रिपा घी प्रवृत्तिः पद दिसंज्ञो बाधकत्वंच संग छते यत्कार्यकालय क्षेप्पे तद्भाष्या संगति निराकरिष्यतः श्रातुः वि प्रतिषेध सूत्रे ऽध्यायी पाठकृतपरत्वं कार्य काल पक्षाश्रयणमात्रे पक्तुमनाम नत्तनपत्र स्पप्रदेशघ स्मदा दिवुद्दिजननेन स्वदेश लागः संभवतीति तद्भाष्प वार्त्तिक्र विरुद्दम्-तथाहि अमीत्र - मूल्यत्रेत्पा दोमी त्वदिर सिदवाद पादयः प्राभुवेतिका दसो मा दितिमत्व संज्ञा या स्तुन सामर्थ्य का ये कालपक्ष*
Romanized Sanskrit
*parimA· shrIgoshAyanamaH mandahRRidayAnaMda nidAnashivayashchirama- namaskuruta herambaniShpratyUhakalAtaye 9 vachchakrIpusta kakarAM puNDarIkA sanasthitAm - shAradAMnIra kuMdendudhavalA bhAvatarAma havApAshi nisUtrANI mita vRRitpartha saMgra hama-paribhAShApradIpArchistatropayanirutAvatparibhAShA nAma livatve sati saMdigdhArtha niyAmaka tvam dIdhIvevITA misAdernadhA tulA 15 sAdaniShedhaH kimikparibhAShAmA uttaguNA vRRidyeoriti saMdigdhArthasmani yAmakatvAtparibhAShAtvasyAdataH sa saMtam saMj~nA sUtrAgavidhipradeshIya saMj~nAbodhakapadarUpa livatvatpa niyAmakatvenAtivyAptiH saMdiggheti tathAsatikvachidereghoH krirityA de| visheSharUpe rAga lokaprasiddhArthaprasA katvAtkvachitpunaH si chinaddiri sAdA va saMdigdhA yeka vAda doShaH - paribhAShA raMgI tu sUtrapAtrApradIpArchinAM ShaShThI rAma0 abhiyoga sAdInAM vidhipradeshagata ShaShTI padAdishravaNaM rUpa liMga vatvena vyAkhyAna i sAdInAM cha j~nApakanpA siddhAnIsadigdhapadAdishravarUpa liMga nisaMdigdhA the niyAmakalA thoka vyavahAra sAta vaNoshra
nAsti payalakSha rAmika desha vikRRitamananpada disAdInAM niShedhAtideshAdirUpAeMge prAchIna tathA vyavahAraH• mArAdhyasAdhAdataevanipAtae kAjitisUtrepana vidhistadetasyAdyaMta vadekasminnityanayoH saMj~nAtideshas trayaH paribhAShA vyavahAra bhAShya yA sAMcha kAryanivIhakatvepayA va Tamena shAstra harapate. pratrAdyamA yatho desha saMj~nA paribhASha· udaya te uchchAryate yasminma denA uchchAra kAlaH- adhika rege gha~na udenA manatika mpati yatheo devarAma yasminkAle pUrvatra patra vA saMj~nAyaribhAShaM muddishyate tatraiva vA vanArtha bodhena gTahItAbhyAM saMj~nApada shaktiparibhAShArthAbhyAM sarvatra shAstra vyavahAraH nanvidamanupapannam - yAvatAkA yethe vAsaMj~nA paribhAShaspakA dashavRRittitvaM nyAyya mAtrA ke yara-yadAnudishya prayojana visheSha prayojanamAtramabhisaMdhAya bhaviShyati kiM chiTnena prayojanamiti se j~nAparibhAShaM pragIyate tadA saMbhava sevA yaM pe so yathAshrutashrAhi pati patra presa iti· mahAvAkyArtha paryAlochanapre vRRitta pratipatra pestu dditIyaH papaisAha - kAryakAla saMj~nA paribhAShama· kAryara
paribhA· kAlpatekhasamIpaM prApyata iti kAryakAlam kArye esva vRRittiliMga vatsaMj~nA paribhAShasvochchAra dinoM saMnidhApyate iti yAta. evaM chaitasmina darshana saMj~nA paribhAShA NAma saMta pArArthyAnna khAte se kArya gamahetutvaM kevala mAnA mero lAghavApAnekapradhAnAMga bhAvapratipattaye ShTathagupadeshaH kRRitaH tatashchahalanaMtarAH saMyogo .adarshanaM lopaH suDiM. taM padaM ShaShThI sthAne yogAlA spaspe tpAdibhirna kiMchitkArya kriyate nApi saMyogota sma lopa isanena kiM tarhisaha tyAtaH saMyogAtaMya sadana] daMyaspa lopa iti mahAvAkyArthaH saMpadyate ityekavAkyatA povaparyAbhAvAtpUrvagraho nAgraha egaj~nA paribhAShA ra pUrvatrA siddhamitya siddhatvaM na pravartata iti sShaShTaM pUrva nAsiddhamiti sUtre bhAShye yatra tu yatheodeo vAliyAghAM pradhAna spa saMskAra iShyate yathA u-mohasvAdilAda| saptamIpaM champuma ye nirdevo parakhA tvacha devadayenasuna tiche dhune tivada muneti vaktavye sukte yoga vibhAgena pUrva vA siDa mitpasikhA dayAdibhirva striyA hone pAdikAnI dirvachanAdInAM keShAMchi honA dudupa
rAma0
dhaspeti sUtre pratyayasyetyukte va pradhAnopaskAra kA kachitripAdyupakArakatvamaMtrI karaNI maM parAdumaya nirdeshe paMchamI nirdeshovalI yA nimitasminniti sUtraM bhAShMM vyAkhyAta kAryakAlayatumayeorekadeshasya vi naparatvAdityukte ra saMgatiH syAt vastutastu u. maityanavakAshana paMchamI nirdeshena mayauttarasUtre charitArtha saptamI nirdesha spatulpavalatvAbhAvAddipratiShedhAtirekadeshinaH shitu pitranashcheti pUrvasUtracharitArthAmAnai tipaMchampAvakAshenashI tisaptamI nirdeshana vAdhanega saMtarA bhAvAcha ataevA kaDArIyabhA disej~nAnAM tripA ghI pravRRittiH pada disaMj~no bAdhakatvaMcha saMga Chate yatkAryakAlaya kSheppe tadbhAShyA saMgati nirAkariShyataH shrAtuH vi pratiShedha sUtre .adhyAyI pAThakRRitaparatvaM kArya kAla pakShAshrayaNamAtre paktumanAma nattanapatra spapradeshagha smadA divuddijananena svadesha lAgaH saMbhavatIti tadbhAShpa vArttikra viruddam-tathAhi amItra - mUlyatretpA domI tvadira sidavAda pAdayaH prAbhuvetikA daso mA ditimatva saMj~nA yA stuna sAmarthya kA ye kAlapakSha*

Is this really about Hinduism?

@CDR Sanskrit is 3 schools of the Vedic religion. So, I think it is very fair to ask. While it may not focus on theological and philosophical attributes the linguistics of the religion is just as important.
